# How to agroup a regex in php without puting in on array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

I have this regex

```
if (preg_match('/(Seg|Segunda)? [aà] (Sex|sexta)?: (de)?\s?(\d{1,2})h?(\d{2})? [aà]s (.*?)h(\d{2})?/is', $obj["horario"], $hora))
```

And If i want to use the array with the values inside on () its like `$hora[1]`, `$hora[2]`... etc, Problem is I dont want to put inside the array the `agrupations` like `(Seg|Segunda)?` because I only want the digit expreisons, any way to dont put them inside?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no Idea what you mean.  Maybe examples?

Comment: Use non-capturing groups - `(Seg|Segunda)` => `(?:Seg|Segunda)`. Does it work the way you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, thanks bro !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only capturing groups in a regex pattern make PHP add items into the resulting `preg_match` array. To avoid putting them there, just convert them to non-capturing ones, add `?:` after the opening `(`. If the group does not contain an alternation operator, then the parentheses may be removed (`(.*?)` => `.*?`).

For example:

```
if (preg_match('/(?:Seg|Segunda)? [aà] (?:Sex|sexta)?: (?:de)?\s?(\d{1,2})h?(\d{2})? [aà]s .*?h(\d{2})?/uis', $obj["horario"], $hora))
```

Now, only digit values will be added as separate items in the array.

Also, since non-ASCII chars are used in the pattern, it is a good idea to pass the `u` modifier that will enable PCRE to parse the input string as a Unicode string.